# Docker PHP 5.2.17 lint doesn't detect anonymous function

Tags: php, docker

So, I am trying to set up several kinds of tests for several kinds of projects.
One project is still running on PHP 5.2.17 (yeah I know :( ).
So I have been searching the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) for PHP 5.2.17 images, which is de PHP version running on the production machine.

On the production machine we recently encountered a fatal error on a PHP file in which we used an anonymous function - a feature that has been added to PHP as of version 5.3.
A simple lint on that machine detects that:

```
php -l corrupt_file.php
```

The above will show an error like "unable to parse PHP file".

However, I have tried out several PHP 5.2.17 docker images, and executing the same lint in them results in "No errors detected".

I am completely lost. Are those PHP 5.2.17's another more recent version of PHP instead??

Comment: Only one way to find out... `docker exec -it [container] php -v`

Comment: The version is actually 5.2.17. I just found the cause of my problem and anwered my own question. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what the problem is:
All the docker images have SHORT_OPEN_TAGS set to "off" in the php.ini.
In that case the PHP linter simply "doesn't see any parse errors" because it doesn't see any PHP.